# How do I throttle mining in Phoenix 2.0 to keep my cards cooler?

Tags: windows, phoenix, throttling

I need my rig to run slower (silent during the day) and full speed at night.  i've figured out a way to replace the config file every x hours but I can't see what settings will actually slow it down.

when it runs full speed the fans are extremely loud @ 80-95degrees. if i can get it to run about 70degress just more than 1/2 speed that would be perfect. I have two ATI cards.

What is the best way to throttle phoenix 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** tweak phoenix to keep your cards cool.

Using stock software like the AMD Catlyst Center you can adjust you settings the way you like them and save it as a preset. Make sure to save the preset in the start menu.

You will make two pre-sets.

1. Maximum Speed - *Clock speeds set to maximum and fan way up*
2. Silence! - *Clocks at minum and fan set as low as possible*

You can then copy the shortcuts to you desktop and double clicking them will apply the pre-sets. Or you can run them using windows scheduler or some remote scripts or triggers.

You just need to find the sweet spots.
for example: 1 x AIT 6990 with stock cooler and OC Switch on (tested 45 minute intervals)

- max - 880clock, +2% power and 72% fan = 75ish celcius @ 770mh(stable)
- min - 500clock, +0% and 38% fan = 75ish celciu stable temp @ 450mh